# passing an array in the shape object of fig.update_layout in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

i get the following error in python for plotly:

```
Invalid element(s) received for the 'shapes' property of layout
        Invalid elements include: ["dict(x0='2021-10-04', x1='2021-10-04', y0=0, y1=1, xref='x', yref='paper', line_width=2),", "dict(x0='2021-11-22', x1='2021-11-22', y0=0, y1=1, xref='x', yref='paper', line_width=2),"]
```

The error comes from this piece of code:

```
shapeArray=[]
shapeArray.append ('dict(x0=\'2021-10-04\', x1=\'2021-10-04\', y0=0, y1=1, xref=\'x\', yref=\'paper\', line_width=2),')
shapeArray.append ('dict(x0=\'2021-11-22\', x1=\'2021-11-22\', y0=0, y1=1, xref=\'x\', yref=\'paper\', line_width=2),')
```

Below is the section that fails in python plotly:

```
fig.update_layout(
    title='purchases',
    yaxis_title='price',
    shapes=shapeArray,
    annotations = [dict(x='2021-10-04', y=0.05, xref='x', yref='paper', showarrow=False, xanchor='left', text='buy0'),],         
)
```

As reference,  annotations has no problems.  I would like to be able to append to shapeArray[] because prior to this code, the application will establish how many shapes need to be added.  For the purpose of this request, i've manually added 2 shapes to the array

Comment: the error is clear. what went is is a list containing 2 strings...  so there are invalid elements.

Comment: users need a minimun reproducable example to help resolve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: why are you creating an array of the arguments as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the dictionaries inside `shapeArray` are strings, when they can be left as dictionaries. You can instead try:

```
shapeArray=[]
shapeArray.append(dict(x0='2021-10-04', x1='2021-10-04', y0=0, y1=1, xref='x', yref='paper', line_width=2))
shapeArray.append(dict(x0='2021-11-22', x1='2021-11-22', y0=0, y1=1, xref='x', yref='paper', line_width=2))
```